# Snowflake query to validate the date field

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to validate date columns it should have case statement if the the date format it should pass or any other format is should fail  and if the date format is any date format it should convert to DD-MM-yyyy format. Can anyone suggest me in snowflake i need to validate the code .

Comment: Can you post the code you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT col, CASE WHEN TRY_TO_DATE(col, 'DD-MM-yyy') IS NULL THEN 'matches format'
                 ELSE 'does not match format'
            END
FROM tab;. This code with input table with datatype as date and input values as ('20170809')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html). When the string does not match the provided format `NULL` is returned instead.

```
SELECT col, CASE WHEN TRY_TO_DATE(col, 'DD-MM-yyy') IS NULL THEN 'matches format'
                 ELSE 'does not match format'
            END
FROM tab;
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this format I'm getting error as unexpected select and it's throwing error and the table I created with datatype as date and values inserted and input values as ('20170809') is this fine can you suggest what I can modify datatype or input format.